# Proofreading in Latex: The delete command in proofread package fails

Tags: proofreading

I am using [proofread](https://ctan.org/pkg/proofread?lang=en) package to correct a latex document (see the MWE and its output). When I delete text using `\del{}` command which spans more than a line in the output (PDF) it fails to start a new line (see the attached image).
Thanks in advance for your help. Below is the MWE and its output:

```
    \documentclass[reprint,amsmath]{revtex4-1}

    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{proofread}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \begin{document}

    \title{Using the proofread package}

    \author{Ashiq e Namurad}
    \affiliation{Koocha e Janaan, Shehr Dilbar}

    \maketitle
    \section{Introduction}

    Baseline datasets are also rare, making trend gathering difficult.
\del{Increasingly, researchers are working with Inuit communities, 
which have a long oral history of species in the region.}

    In recent years, killer whales, or orcas, have also become more
frequent in a number, taking advantage of longer ice-free seasons. 
The whales, which feast on resident narwhal, have even started 
changing narwhal behaviour, according to a 2017 report by the 
Department of Fisheries and Oceans. (Report from The Guardian)

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems to fail to break lines no matter what document class one is using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that commands from the `soul` package may not be nested; the combined overstriking and highlighting in the `\del` command of the `proofread` package is therefore done by overstriked the text in a savebox and then highlight that box. However, this forces the text on a single line. 
I'll upload a new version with the overstriking removed:

```
\newcommand{\del}[1]{%
  \com{delete}%
  \hilite[red]{#1}%
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. And it does fix the problem - although - deleted text with strikethrough looked much more appealing and intuitive.